# What is the best aproach to display images in different devices: CSS3 or jQuery resizing?

Tags: image, jquery, css

I have a webpage with different images of different proportions. I want to display in the best format for different devices: desktop, tablet, smartphone, etc.

Is it best to use CSS3 `@media (mx-width: ** px )` or **jQuery** `$( window ).resize(function()` and `$( document ).ready(function() {` with a change in the size of the image?

The last step works very well and does not require to set a lot of different media sizes as in the case of CSS3, but if Javascript is disabled it will not work.

Basically, I want the images to be responsive, but not with re-scaling of the screen of the device, which is what I get with the Javascript code, but offering the full width of the container div when the page and images are displayed in a smartphone. I think that the approach would involve PHP code to get the Client data ( `$_SERVER['USER_AGENT']` ) because don't want images to be too big to go outside the screen, and when using a smartphone I don't want the images to be too small  to be seen, and here I have the problem of screen resolutio: the pixels of  the image can be 1200 px, but it is shown very small because of screen pixel density or resolution.

Comment: For design only purpose, the best is always CSS only solution. Now: `Javascript is disabled it will not work` True, but as the opposite, older browsers won't support CSS media queries

Comment: Thanks for your question, you are rigth about CSS3 compatibility. I have reworked the question.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach these days is using a technique called "responsive image sizes" along with good old CSS to handle image scaling on devices with similar screen sizes.

Using `'resize'` event to manipulate the DOM with jQuery is a staging way to bad performance and bad user experience.

The core idea is to load smaller images on smaller screens and down-scale them in browser if image is bigger than required, using:

```
img { 
    display: block;
    /* You should never upscale raster images in browser */
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Here is a good article, that covers the concept in details: [Responsive Images in Practice](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-images-in-practice)

I would recommend checking out [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes), it implements lazy-loading as a bonus.

This is how you use it in your markup:

```
<img
    data-sizes="auto"
    data-src="image2.jpg"
    data-srcset="image1.jpg 300w,
    image2.jpg 600w,
    image3.jpg 900w" class="lazyload" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That approach is very nice, but unfortunately, as it is not adopted by all browsers, I cannot take it. The problem I have is better explained in the re-worked question.